# What to do when a user's profile is advertising websites that are 'off-topic'

Tags: discussion, support

So... I found a user and her profile is basically a gold farmers ad for diablo 3 and WoW. What can I do about this?

Comment: Nothing, you can put whatever (within reason) you want in your profile

Comment: @JQAn Generally yes, if that user's only contribution to the site was some spam post, I see no reason not to delete the whole profile.

Comment: @Mad, sure, but that's apart from what he's asking

Comment: Related MSO question: [Rules for Profiles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31504/158605)

Comment: @Rachel's linked question's answer flat out says that spam is not allowed in profiles.

Comment: Highly related:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139190

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's outright spam, flag a post by that user for moderator attention and explain what's going on.

Comment: Just keep in mind that user profiles are not "in the way" -- nobody forces you to look at them, I don't think we can call that "spam"

Comment: @JQAn I have to disagree to a point. Keep in mind that a common tactic these sites use is trying to 'piggyback' on sites like this one to leave their links up someplace that Google will index in hopes of getting a little bit more of that magical Search Engine Juice that the SE Network has so much of. For example, I suspect [this user](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/28612/may-lee) is the one in question. The only question asked is entirely worthless, and the profile is *nothing but* spam.

Comment: Quite sure that is the user in question, and I'd vote for 'nothing' **in this case** (profile) - but I also noticed a couple of links were in a question and edited out, trying to add them there would be grounds for action imho.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz, links in profiles are no-follow (unless you have  2k rep, when only your "website" is a normal link)

Comment: Agreed with Juan.  If the user is abusing the site then scrubbing their profile might be part of any disciplinary action to be taken, but if an otherwise constructive poster had spam in their profile then nothing would need to be done unless it was also offensive.

Comment: @MatthewRead Right, but you're talking about something that *basically never happens*. It's great to bring up these thought experiments about this mythical quality user who happens to have links to kind-of-shady business websites in their profile, but that user *does not exist*. Spammers are spammers are spammers and should be summarily dealt with as such.

Comment: I've seen such users on other sites.  Ignore what's in someone's profile unless it's offensive, it doesn't *need* to be dealt with.

Answer (score 6):

I have to disagree with @LessPop_MoreFizz:  I don't see how *anything* in a profile could be considered spam, really.  According to [Rules for Profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/31505/141513):

> **Generally speaking, your profile is (to an extent) fair game**, as it is a reflection of you as a person, not the site as a whole.
>
> **Self-promotion,** your e-mail address, humor, (if you know HTML) imagery and even the f-bomb are allowed there.
>
> There are reasonable limitations for all of those, but generally speaking, **unless you're a hard-core spammer or you put something truly offensive / crazy in there (like hate speech or pornography)**, you'll be OK

So if I own a gold-farming business, or a poker website, or a business that sells male-enhancement pills, I should be allowed to advertise that business in my profile like any other business - whether or not you consider those businesses to be "spam-ish" is irrelevant.

**As long as the user is not advertising their gold-farming business outside of their profile** (which *would* be considered spam), or creating multiple accounts or other obvious abuses, **I say, let it be.**

Comment: @Downvoters:  Would you like to explain?  According to the rules, a link to a gold-farming site is perfectly acceptable in a profile, unless you consider having one link on your personal profile as *"hardcore spamming"* - in which case, I think you should look up the definition of "spam"...

Comment: These aren't accounts being used by real individuals typing real answes we're talking about. They're pretty clearly being automatically registered by bots and posting garbage. There's no reason to leave the profiles in the DB after clearing out the rest of the garbage they've spewed on the site, and we've had a pretty severe uptick in flat out spam like this in the past few weeks.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: If it's a bunch of accounts automatically generated, that's a different story - that's clearly spam.  But that wasn't mentioned in the question/comments/answers anywhere.

Comment: There's a bit of a hierarchy of rules in effect here. If you're a member in good standing, sure - put whatever you want in your profile. If you look like you're just here to abuse the site and its members, then a dodgy profile doesn't really help your case - chances are, it gets deleted.